# Delay-load of XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml

I'm writing an XML document based on a stream of data. This part has been accomplished using the `XmlTextWriter` and the `XElement` classes.

Now when I come to read in the document I want to be able to 'delay-load' the XML document so that certain nodes are skipped (i.e. the ones which contain large binary chunks.) and then load them when required.

Is this possible using the `XmlDocument` class? Or will I have to do things in a more manual way using the `XmlTextReader` class.

Thanks.

Nick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible with `XmlDocument` as the whole document needs to be loaded onto memory before parsed as tree.

XmlTextReader/SAX is the standard solution.

Comment: If it's the standard solution, any chance you could provide a link? :)

Comment: Have a look at `Skip()` method here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ye3b7te.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with either `XmlDocument` or `XDocument`.

Answer (score 0):

note that if you want to use XmlTextReader, it is fwd only. i.e. once youhave skipped it, you cant come back to it.

[see MSDN on this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader.aspx)